# ESP-IDF installation throws up Python errors

Tags: python, esp32, esp-idf

I'm sorry to be a bother but I've been trying to get started with ESP32 for days and I'm out of energy.

1. https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/v4.4.1/esp32/get-started/index.html
2. https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/v4.4.1/esp32/get-started/linux-setup.html
3. https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/v4.4.1/esp32/get-started/windows-setup.html#get-started-windows-tools-installer

I've sorted "Step 1. Install Prerequisites" (all the apt packages); that's fine.

Now, "Step 2. Get ESP-IDF". It suggests some Git stuff I don't understand, and there is no internet on the machine, but I downloaded the zip from GitHub:

https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/releases/tag/v4.4.1

This is where I start to get lost.

> The source files attached to this release will not work due to our use of git submodules.

Not sure what that means but is that why the `.git` dir in the zip is 750 MB?! O_o

> Attached to this release is an `esp-idf-v4.4.1.zip` archive. It includes `.git` directory and all the submodules, so can be used out of the box. This archive is provided for users who have connectivity issues preventing them from cloning from GitHub.

Okay... Not 100% sure what that means, but it sounds good ("can be used out of the box"), and that's what I downloaded, the big one.

Now, "Step 3. Set up the tools":

> Aside from the ESP-IDF, you also need to install the tools used by ESP-IDF, such as the compiler, debugger, Python packages, etc, for projects supporting ESP32.
>
> `cd ~/esp/esp-idf`
> `./install.sh esp32`

I configured the `IDF_TOOLS_PATH` to where I want it to unpack the toolchain, but when I run `install.sh`, it doesn't install, it just tries to download things:

```
Detecting the Python interpreter
Checking "python" ...
Checking "python3" ...
Python 3.7.3
"python3" has been detected
Installing ESP-IDF tools
WARNING: File /Espressif/IDF/tools/idf-env.json was not found. 
Creating /Espressif/IDF/tools/idf-env.json
Selected targets are: esp32, esp32c3, esp32s3, esp32s2
Installing tools: xtensa-esp32-elf, xtensa-esp32s2-elf, xtensa-esp32s3-elf, riscv32-esp-elf, esp32ulp-elf, esp32s2ulp-elf, openocd-esp32
Installing xtensa-esp32-elf@esp-2021r2-patch3-8.4.0
Downloading xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc8_4_0-esp-2021r2-patch3-linux-amd64.tar.gz to /Espressif/IDF/tools/dist/xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc8_4_0-esp-2021r2-patch3-linux-amd64.tar.gz.tmp
WARNING: Download failure <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>
WARNING: Failed to download https://github.com/espressif/crosstool-NG/releases/download/esp-2021r2-patch3/xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc8_4_0-esp-2021r2-patch3-linux-amd64.tar.gz to /Espressif/IDF/tools/dist/xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc8_4_0-esp-2021r2-patch3-linux-amd64.tar.gz.tmp
Downloading xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc8_4_0-esp-2021r2-patch3-linux-amd64.tar.gz to /Espressif/IDF/tools/dist/xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc8_4_0-esp-2021r2-patch3-linux-amd64.tar.gz.tmp
WARNING: Download failure <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>
WARNING: Failed to download https://github.com/espressif/crosstool-NG/releases/download/esp-2021r2-patch3/xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc8_4_0-esp-2021r2-patch3-linux-amd64.tar.gz to /Espressif/IDF/tools/dist/xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc8_4_0-esp-2021r2-patch3-linux-amd64.tar.gz.tmp
Downloading xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc8_4_0-esp-2021r2-patch3-linux-amd64.tar.gz to /Espressif/IDF/tools/dist/xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc8_4_0-esp-2021r2-patch3-linux-amd64.tar.gz.tmp
WARNING: Download failure <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>
WARNING: Failed to download https://github.com/espressif/crosstool-NG/releases/download/esp-2021r2-patch3/xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc8_4_0-esp-2021r2-patch3-linux-amd64.tar.gz to /Espressif/IDF/tools/dist/xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc8_4_0-esp-2021r2-patch3-linux-amd64.tar.gz.tmp
ERROR: Failed to download, and retry count has expired
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Espressif/IDF/esp-idf-v4.4.1/tools/idf_tools.py", line 1858, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/Espressif/IDF/esp-idf-v4.4.1/tools/idf_tools.py", line 1854, in main
    action_func(args)
  File "/Espressif/IDF/esp-idf-v4.4.1/tools/idf_tools.py", line 1468, in action_install
    tool_obj.download(tool_version)
  File "/Espressif/IDF/esp-idf-v4.4.1/tools/idf_tools.py", line 721, in download
    raise DownloadError()
__main__.DownloadError
```

So evidently the big zip still does not contain the toolchain. The *Windows* instructions contain some clues:

> If you wish to download ESP-IDF without the help of ESP-IDF Tools Installer, refer to these [instructions](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/v4.4.1/esp32/get-started/windows-setup-scratch.html#get-esp-idf-windows-command-line).

Those instructions tell me to set up CMake, Ninja, and Python, which I have done. Then it tells me how to finally set up the toolchain:

> Download the precompiled Windows toolchain:
>
> https://dl.espressif.com/dl/xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc8_4_0-esp-2021r2-patch3-win32.zip
>
> Unzip the zip file to C:\Program Files (or some other location). The zip file contains a single directory xtensa-esp32-elf.
>
> Next, the bin subdirectory of this directory must be added to your Path. For example, the directory to add may be C:\Program Files\xtensa-esp32-elf\bin

I eventually uncovered this page with binaries for other platforms:

https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/v4.4.1/esp32/api-guides/tools/idf-tools.html

> The following sections explain the installation method, and provide the list of tools installed on each platform.
>
> [...]
>
> Although the methods above are recommended for ESP-IDF users, they are not a must for building ESP-IDF applications. ESP-IDF build system expects that all the necessary tools are installed somewhere, and made available in the `PATH`.

That sounds reasonable. So I visit the various GitHub pages for the named tools and download and extract them into their own directories:

1. xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc11_2_0-esp-2022r1-RC1-linux-amd64.tar.xz
2. binutils-esp32ulp-linux-amd64-2.28.51-esp-20191205.tar.gz
3. openocd-esp32-linux-amd64-0.11.0-esp32-20220706.tar.gz

Each has a `bin` subdir, which I prepend to `PATH`.

But `install.sh` still wants to download them. I'm not sure how to tell it the tools are already installed, so, I guess we're not supposed to use it any more? And was the 750 MB .git dir just cruft?

I guess we're on to ["Step 4. Set up the environment variables"](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/v4.4.1/esp32/get-started/index.html#step-4-set-up-the-environment-variables).

> In the terminal where you are going to use ESP-IDF, run:
>
> `. $HOME/esp/esp-idf/export.sh`

The `export.sh` script doesn't work because it's symmetric with `install.sh` and thinks the tools aren't installed, but that should be okay because the instructions say it's okay to just make the tools available on the path manually, which I've done.

I also found a script called `add_path.sh` in the same dir, which also adds some Python scripts in the IDF to the path, including the crucial `idf.py`. Finally we're getting somewhere!

So now I navigate to the Hello World example dir in the IDF, and we're on to ["Step 7. Configure"](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/v4.4.1/esp32/get-started/index.html#step-7-configure).

As instructed, I execute:

```
idf.py set-target esp32
```

It turns out this goes nowhere. Apparently it's still missing things:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Espressif/IDF/esp-idf-v4.4.1/tools/idf.py", line 36, in <module>
    from idf_py_actions.tools import executable_exists, idf_version, merge_action_lists, realpath  # noqa: E402
  File "/Espressif/IDF/esp-idf-v4.4.1/tools/idf_py_actions/tools.py", line 7, in <module>
    import click
ImportError: No module named click
```

I have triple-checked and I am ***sure*** I am using the "can be used out of the box" `esp-idf-v4.4.1.zip`, so this shouldn't really happen. It's made worse by the fact that I don't know Python.

I found a script `esp-idf-v4.4.1/tools/check_python_dependencies.py`. This says:

```
The following Python requirements are not satisfied:
setuptools>=21
click>=7.0
pyserial>=3.3
pyparsing>=2.0.3,<2.4.0
pyelftools>=0.22
idf-component-manager~=1.0
gdbgui==0.13.2.0
pygdbmi<=0.9.0.2
python-socketio<5
jinja2<3.1  # See https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/issues/8760
itsdangerous<2.1
kconfiglib==13.7.1
reedsolo>=1.5.3,<=1.5.4
bitstring>=3.1.6
ecdsa>=0.16.0
construct==2.10.54
Please follow the instructions found in the "Set up the tools" section of ESP-IDF Getting Started Guide
Diagnostic information:
    IDF_PYTHON_ENV_PATH: (not set)
    Python interpreter used: /usr/bin/python
    Warning: python interpreter not running from IDF_PYTHON_ENV_PATH
    PATH: /Espressif/IDF/esp-idf-v4.4.1/components/esptool_py/esptool/:/Espressif/IDF/esp-idf-v4.4.1/components/espcoredump/:/Espressif/IDF/esp-idf-v4.4.1/components/partition_table/:/Espressif/IDF/esp-idf-v4.4.1/tools/:/Espressif/IDF/toolchain/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/:/Espressif/IDF/toolchain/esp32ulp-elf-binutils/bin/:/Espressif/IDF/toolchain/openocd-esp32/bin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

I downloaded and installed `python-click_7.0-1_all.deb` (`python3-click`, "Wrapper around optparse for command line utilities"). It's definitely installed. But there is no change to the error message or the dependencies report. And the instructions are at their end.

Clearly something has gone spectacularly badly wrong.

Help?

---

Update: I made some progress. It turns out that `python` in Debian was defaulting to Python 2. I created a symlink `ln -s /usr/bin/python3 python` and put it in a dir on the path. This satisfied the "click" dependency.

But the Hello World example still does not compile, complaining of more missing Python packages. There are some obscure packages which Debian doesn't seem to support and which I cannot find in the big ESP-IDF zip and I don't know how to install:

- idf-component-manager
- gdbgui
- pygdbmi
- kconfiglib
- reedsolo

This all just shouldn't be happening.

---

Update 2: Digging around in `idf_tools.py`, it says:

> It can also create a Python virtual environment, and install Python requirements into it.

Because I don't know Python I don't understand everything this code is doing, but it's clearly designed to download a lot of stuff. This would imply that dependencies missing from the big zip is intentional, even if the instructions claim that things are complete as-is.

It's invoking a further script called "pip" to set up Python packages, but I can't for the life of me work out **where** it wants me to get all of the packages from, and pip itself seems to admit it doesn't know:

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/secure-installs/

> pip does not perform any checks to protect against remote tampering and involves running arbitrary code

---

Update 3:

Everything I'm reading about that Python packager, if it's the same one, says it's notorious for frequent, cataclysmic security breaches:

1. https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2021/07/malicious-pypi-packages-caught-stealing-developer-data-and-injecting-code/
2. https://securityaffairs.co/wordpress/124861/hacking/malicious-pypi-python-packages.html
3. https://portswigger.net/daily-swig/dependency-confusion-attack-mounted-via-pypi-repo-exposes-flawed-package-installer-behavior
4. https://therecord.media/python-team-fixes-bug-that-allowed-takeover-of-pypi-repository/
5. https://www.theregister.com/2021/03/02/python_pypi_purges/

There's just no way this can be the correct instructions. Is this **REALLY** the intended way to use ESP32?

Or are the missing files packed in the big "git submodules" blob? I **still** haven't managed to decode what's in there.

Or am I just missing another zip file somewhere?

Comment: Download Visual Studio code (vscode), it’s free, and after downloading go to extensions and install the espressif extension. There you can choose to install a new copy of the idf. There are multiple ways, but I guess this is the easiest.

Comment: @RemyHx The Espressif extension .vsix file is only 5 MB. So it's incomplete too unfortunately.

Comment: Yes but it gives like a menu option to do a guided download.

Comment: @RemyHx There is no internet on the machine. This is the whole point. This is why I already [gave up on PlatformIO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72975878/is-it-possible-to-use-platformio-offline). I need to download and copy files manually.

Comment: Ah ok. Take a look here: https://dl.espressif.com/dl/esp-idf/?idf=4.4

Comment: @RemyHx No joy. They're all for Windows.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question… but you are able to use internet for Stack Overflow. Isn’t it possible to take the computer temporarily to the location where you have internet? Otherwise only option is to really download everything… Or use Arduino - esp

Comment: @RemyHx It's disconnected *deliberately* for safety, which, as the Python situation shows, is not just paranoia. I wanted to use ESP-IDF because my understanding is it has fuller features and better IDE support. But the installation procedure is so shoddy I don't know if I really want it any more. Yes I am experimenting with the Arduino-esp thing too, to see if that can be made to cooperate.

Comment: @RemyHx Arduino-esp also expects some additional downloads, but it wasn't too difficult. Seems to be working well. Thanks for help.